# Anagram sorting version vs Counting characters version

Tags: python, time-complexity, anagram, timeit

I am learning about the Time-complexity and theoretically I've read that to check Anagram for two string of same lengths there can be two version:

1. Sorting the string and comparing O(nlogn)
2. Counting the characters O(n)

but I wanted to go ahead and experience the same using code also.

So I've written the two version of the code and check time using python timeit module but there I'm getting different results.

```
import timeit


def method_one(input1, input2):
    """
    Check if two string are anagram 
    """

    if len(input1) == len(input2):
        if sorted(input1) == sorted(input2):
            return True
    return False

def method_two(input1, input2):
    """
    Check if two string are anagram using count the character method
    """
    count_char = [0] * 26

    if len(input1) == len(input2):
        for i in range(0, len(input1)):
            count_char[ord(input1[i])-ord("a")] += 1
            count_char[ord(input2[i])-ord("a")] -= 1

        for i in count_char:
            if(bool(i)):
                return False
        return True
    return False

timer1 = timeit.Timer("method_one('apple','pleap')", "from __main__ import method_one")
timer2 = timeit.Timer("method_two('apple','pleap')", "from __main__ import method_two")

print(timer1.timeit(number=10000))
print(timer2.timeit(number=10000))
```

```
method_one: 0.0203204
method_two: 0.1090699
```

Ideally counting chars should be winning this but results are opposite to what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Time complexity describes how the execution time of the algorithm scales when the input to said algorithm increases. Since it ignores constants, an algorithm which has a better time complexity it not guarantee to run faster than others with higher bounds.

What time complexity tells you is that as the input size approaches infinity then the most efficient algorithm will run faster.